# Randomly split users into two groups in the percentage of 80:20

Tags: python

I have a list of ids called users and want to split them randomly into two groups by the percentage of 80:20.

For example i have a list of 100 users ids and randomly put 80 users into group1 and remaining 20 into group2

```
 def getLevelForIncrementality(Object[] args) {
   try {
     if (args.length >= 1 && args[0]!="") {
        String seed = args[0] + "Testing";
        int rnd = Math.abs(seed.hashCode() % 100);
        return (rnd >= 80 ? 2 : 1);
     }
  } catch (Exception e) { }
 return 3;
}
```

I have tried from the above groovy code which gives me in the ratio of 82:18.

Can someone give me some insights or suggestions or alogrithms which can solve the above problem for millions of user ids.

Comment: you want the solution in php or python?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal i want it in python

Answer (score 5):

You can use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.sample) to randomly extract the needed number of elements:

```
import random

a = list(range(1000))

b = random.sample(a, int(len(a) * 0.8))
len(b)
```

> `800`

If you have unique IDs, you can try to convert these lists of IDs to sets and differ them like this:

```
c = list(set(a) - set(b))
```

Comment: if i don't have a list, for example if i'm getting the traffic of users from many devices each one by one into the log as user ids. here the user id is the device id. How can we try .?

Comment: `random.sample` should work with any sequences or sets. If you have some complex structure, you should convert it to list, for example. But if you have some kind of distributed flow of objects, I think the only case that is good for you is to move it to one group with 80% probability and to another in another case.

Comment: my concerns is if i have some million users and if i put them into list, what will be the speed and memory to divide them randomly into two groups.?

Comment: Should be `O(n)`. Not very slow and not very much memory if each user is not a huge object. Anyway you will need memory for samples that will be equal to the memory of the initial bunch of millions of users.

Comment: yea, when ever i get an entry into the logs, i just have distribute them in the ratio of 80:20, thats why i have used hashCode in groovy.

Answer (score 2):

In order to distribute data "on the fly" without creating large lists, you can use a small control list that will tell you how to part users into the two groups (by chunks of 5).

```
spread = []
while getNextUser():
    if not spread
        spread = [1,1,1,1,0] # number of 1s and 0s is 4 vs 1 (80%)
        random.shuffle(spread)
    if spread.pop():
        # place on 80% side
    else:
        # place on 20% side
```

This will ensure a perfect 80:20 split every fifth user through with a maximum imbalance of 4.  As more users are processed this imbalance will become less and less significant.

Worst cases:

- 19.2% instead of 20% after 99 users, corrects to perfect 20% at 100
- 19.9% after 999 users, corrects to perfect 20% at 1000
- 19.99% after 9999 users, corrects to perfect 20% at 10000

*Note: you can change the number of 1s and 0s in the `spread` list to get a different proportion.  e.g.  [1,1,0] will give you 2 vs 1;  [1,1,1,0] is 3 vs 1 (75:25);  [1]*13+[0]*7 is 13 vs 7 (65:35)*

You can generalize this into a generator that will do the proper calculations and initializations for you:

```
import random
from math import gcd
def spreadRatio(a,b):
    d      = gcd(a,b) 
    base   = [True]*(a//d)+[False]*(b//d)
    spread = []
    while True:
        if not spread:
            spread = base.copy()
            random.shuffle(spread)
        yield spread.pop()


pareto = spreadRatio(80,20)
while getNextUser():
    if next(pareto):
        # place on 80% side
    else:
        # place on 20% side
```

Answer (score 2):

it can be also done using train_test_split of sklearn

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = list(np.arange(1000))

x_80_percent, x_20_percent =  train_test_split(X, test_size =.20, shuffle  = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works for spliting a list:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16] ## Sample List
l = (len(A)/10) *8 ## making 80 %
B = A[:int(l)] ## Getting 80% of list
C = A[int(l):] ## Getting remaining list
```

Comment: if i don't have a list, for example if i'm getting the traffic of users from many devices each one by one into the log as user ids. here the user id is the device id. How can we try .?

Comment: OP wants to split them *randomly*, not just pick 80% first and 20% last.